# Lyx new equation line

Tags: lyx, line-breaking, line

[image: see]

I have written the above expression in lyx using command+ return for new lines. But if I need only two equations as shown, how can I delete the rest 4 rows!!!

Answer (score 2):

Without being sure which LyX-Version you're on, there should be a panel looking like this at the bottom (for me using Version 2.3.5.2 using Linux):

[image: Table commands]

Place your cursor on the line you wish to remove and click the third last button.

This should do it.

Comment: Any shortcuts with keyboard button?

Comment: Yes, the `del`-key on your keyboard or if on a Mac  `fn + Delete` ;-)

Comment: This is what I was exactly looking for